# Why would Black Widow use taser on a guy with Infinity Stones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Black Widow uses taser on Thanos. Maybe, she didn't know that Thanos was more powerful than the Hulk, but she definitely knew about the Infinity Stones.

What made her think that a taser would work on Thanos?

[image: Black Widow running with a taser]

Comment: When you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail

Comment: I didn't see the movie, but did she have some pressing reason *not* to taser him and see what happened? I mean, we as viewers understand that "you can't just shoot the villain, it's undramatic" but the characters don't usually see it that way.

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, this question (or at least the various memes that it's echoing) smacks of misogyny. How is her *pointlessly ineffective attack* any different from the wide range of other *pointlessly ineffective attacks* that Thanos faces from male Avengers and others? - "***Why would Captain America try punching a guy with Infinity Stones?"***

Comment: I don't think this question is misogynistic, but it's definitely on the verge of being considered opinion based like all other questions of the type why didn't X do Y.

Comment: @Loki - You're just upset that your plan to kill Thanos didn't work either.

Comment: @Adamant You're right, you got me :)

Answer (score 12):

I think you have to ask yourself what the alternative is. Basically all of the Avengers (and their new buddies) try to ***get him with what they got***. Loki tried to stab him with a knife, Gamora tried to stab him with a knife, Nebula tried to stab him with a sword, Banner tried to punch him, Black Panther tried to claw him, Falcon tried to shoot him with pistols, War Machine tried hitting him with rockets and bullets, Okoye threw a Wakandan spear, Bucky shot at him with a powerful rifle, Groot tried to cover him in vines and Cap'n America's master plan was to punch him a few times. **With that in mind, how is using a high-tech taser any less of a good/bad idea than any of the above?**

The other option would have been for her to spend time looking around for gun (bad idea, she might not find one) or try kicking him several times (bad idea, he's very strong). Neither of which is an especially good idea. And heck, the taser might have worked. *How stupid would it have been not to at least try it?*

---

You might also want to note that in the prior films, her electricity-based weapons have always proven consistently *effective* against aliens and other baddies.

Comment: You might as well mention the people who had good ideas, too (insofar as they worked better): Wanda tried to fry him with mystical energy; Doctor Strange tried to see the future, trap him in the mirror dimension, and do other things; Thor tried to hit him with lightning and a super-axe.